# so files: function called from another so file than intended

Tags: c++, c, linux

Lets say my executable file, MyApp, links dynamically against an so file, boost-system.so. I compile and everything works fine for a while; my calls to boost-system funcs do what they are supposed to do.

After a while i realize i need to link to another so file, SomeAPI.so. However, SomeAPI.so have statically linked against boost-system.a, but an older, buggy version, which has functions with exactly the same names as "my" boost-system (ofcourse). Now, ALL calls (both from MyApp and SomeAPI) will go to the version SomeAPI statically linked (or my version of boost-system, depending on link order, both are bad for me).

I would like my calls from MyApp to go to my version of boost-system, and SomeAPI to use its statically linked boost-system.a functions. On Windows this is how it works.

I realize why this is not happening, but is there any way around this except renaming the namespaces in "my" boost-system to something local?

Comment: What you described is the main pitfall of static linking of widely used libraries. I would be also interested to know if there's a clean solution. Did you try linking boost statically in your app as well?

Comment: I _think_ the only way to achieve this would be to rebuild `SomeAPI.so` in such a way that it doesn't statically link with `boost-system.so`.

Comment: What about manual dynamic loading at run-time both new `boost-system.so` with `RTLD_LOCAL`, and then `SomeAPI.so`? Will that not force to load old `boost-system.so` for `SomAPI.so` when needed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible to building SomeAPI.so so that it doesn't export the symbols of boost-system.a with a linker scripts (gcc sometimes ago added support for attribute to achieve the same effect, but linker script is perhaps easier in your setup).  I think but I'm not sure that it is also possible to ensure that symbols from boost-system.a are used for SomeAPI.so even if boost-system.so is linked.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, if I'm not mistaken, symbols of boost-system.so could be optained only with dlsym, probably not desired.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Ive tried that, and then both myapp and someapi will still use the same .so file. But as others have said, I guess that is how its supposed to work with the Linux architecture

Comment: You may create your own SomeAPI.so that contains only dummy functions. If you use C (not C++) then all functions may be "void xxx(void)". The file should only contain the "good" functions and not the functions you want to take from the other .so file. Then you link against this SomeAPI.so file and delete/rename the file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LD version scripts](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/LD-Version-Scripts.html) to hide function names that you don't want other .so files to see.